# Find the limit of Riemann's sum

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, riemann-sum

I have a question about the limit of Riemann’s sum. My Riemann’s sum is $\displaystyle   \sum_{i=1}^{2n}  \left(3 + \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\right)\frac{1}{n}$. I tried to calculate the values of this sum using Sage but it was increasing as n was 10, 100, 1000, and did not approach any number. However, Symbolab says that there is a limit actually and it is 26/3.

Can you please help me to write integral and solve it for this problem?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum ^{2n}_{i=1}\left( 3+\frac{i^{2}}{n^{2}}\right) =\frac{1}{n}\left( 6n+\frac{2n( 2n+1)( 4n+1)}{6n^{2}}\right)\\
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n}\left( 6n+\frac{2n( 2n+1)( 4n+1)}{6n^{2}}\right) =\frac{26}{3}\\
\\
\end{gather*}

Comment: That looks great! Thank you! But how I can rewrite this as an integral? Do you have an idea? I thought it will be just integral of 3+(x)^2

Comment: You are absolutely right. It will be the integral of 3+(x)^2, limits zero to 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Note that
\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{i=1}^{2n}  \left(3 + \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2\right)\frac{1}{n}&=&\sum_{1\leq i \leq 2n} \frac{3+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)}{n}\\
&=&\sum_{1\leq i \leq 2n}\frac{3}{n}+\frac{i^{2}}{nn^{2}}\\
&=&\sum_{1\leq i \leq 2n}\frac{3}{n}+n^{-3}i^{2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{3n^{2}}+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{26}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This's a hint, so I think you can complete each the details.